# Importing GEE python coordinate data into QGIS

Tags: qgis, geojson, google-earth-engine

I have a .csv file with data and coordinates for that data in GeoJSON format:

```
{"geodesic":false,"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-76.24486906575804,39.72835276629949],[-76.2445995711728,39.72835276629949],[-76.2445995711728,39.72862226088473],[-76.24486906575804,39.72862226088473],[-76.24486906575804,39.72835276629949]]]}
```

How can I pull the data into a software like QGIS and map it?

The data is "mean" and the location is under the column geo.

Example of top of csv:
[image]

Comment: I don't think QGIS can understand geometry data in that format. Can you convert it to [WKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry) or [GML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geography_Markup_Language) format?

Comment: Why not export the `ee.FeatureCollection` as "GeoJSON" format instead of "CSV".

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Google Earth Engine plugin installed in QGIS, you can simply pass that JSON object to ee.Geometry() constructor, only change true to True to make it Python-compatible:

```py
import ee
from ee_plugin import Map

json = {"geodesic":False,"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-76.24486906575804,39.72835276629949],[-76.2445995711728,39.72835276629949],[-76.2445995711728,39.72862226088473],[-76.24486906575804,39.72862226088473],[-76.24486906575804,39.72835276629949]]]}

geom = ee.Geometry(json)

Map.addLayer(geom, { 'color': 'yellow' }, 'geom')
Map.centerObject(geom)
```

[image]